# ProgressDialog gets dismissed when button is pressed

Tags: android

I have a "please wait" `ProgressDialog` that includes a button, the problem is that when the button is clicked the dialog is **dismissed** (it disappears), how can I make the dialog **stay on the screen**?

```
    // Please wait dialog
private void showWaitDialog() {
    prgDialg = new ProgressDialog(context);
    prgDialg.setTitle("Working...");
    prgDialg.setMessage("Please wait.");
    prgDialg.setCancelable(false);
    prgDialg.setButton("Do something", myListener);
    prgDialg.show();
}

// Click listener
public OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        textViev1.setText("xxx");
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need a button in progress dialog?

Comment: By definition, if you use a built in button on a Dialog, it will dismiss the dialog. If you want to have more interaction with the Dialog, you will need to add a View to it containing the buttons etc that you want.

Comment: @NareshR For example, a **Cancel** button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent ProgressDialog from getting dismissed by onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579030/prevent-progressdialog-from-getting-dismissed-by-onclick)

Comment: @JoshPinter For that you need to create a custom dialog using DialogFragment and place the ProgressBar and Cancel Button.

Comment: @NareshR Not true, you can easily use a **`ProgressDialog`** with a `setButton` to create a cancel button. However, you need to set the `onClickListener` after the `ProgressDialog` has been rendered.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
prgDialg.setButton("Do something", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            // Use either finish() or return() to either close the activity or just the dialog
            return;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't prevent the `ProgressDialog` from closing using this method, regardless of what you put in the `onClickListener`. You need to set the `onClickListener` after the `ProgressDialog` has been shown.

Comment: @JoshPinter, This actually helped me. Thank you.

Comment: @Mann You bet. Check out this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24843394/293280

Answer (score -1):

> > prgDialg.setButton("Do something", myListener);
> >     the above method setButton(CharSequence text, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) is deprecated.

you can use

```
private void showWaitDialog() {
    prgDialg = new ProgressDialog(this);
    prgDialg.setTitle("Working...");
    prgDialg.setMessage("Please wait.");
    prgDialg.setCancelable(false);
    prgDialg.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Do something", this);
    prgDialg.show();
}

@Override
public void cancel() {

}

@Override
public void dismiss() {

}
```

Comment: This still dismisses the `ProgressDialog` when the button is clicked.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void showWaitDialog() {
    prgDialg = new ProgressDialog(context);
    prgDialg.setTitle("Working...");
    prgDialg.setMessage("Please wait.");
    prgDialg.setCancelable(false);
    prgDialg.setNeutralButton("Do Something", new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                textViev1.setText("xxx");
    }
    });
    prgDialg.show();
}
```

Comment: I don't have `setNeutralButton` available. Where'd you get that from?